# How do I change what outputs from my select based on whether it exists in another table

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I am trying to select whether or not a name is already in my customer table.

This is what I want to do, but I am getting the error "the case construct is not supported with a subselect. Thank you for any help.

```sql
select id, 
     if(description not in 
          (select name 
              from customer 
             where type in ('A', 'B','C')), 
       'NOT A CUSTOMER', description) 
from names
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, what your sql engine told you... Try one of these approaches:

1. use **two selects** and union. One select with "customers only" and other without,
2. try to use **exists** in subquery,
3. join tables and have column with possibly null value and handle it on client side.
4. 

```sql
union(
    select id,
        c.description
        if(description not in (select name from customer where , 
    from names n
    left join customer c ON (c.id == n.customer_id)
    where n.type in ('A', 'B','C')
,
    select id,
        'NOT A CUSTOMER'
    from names n
    left join customer c ON (c.id == n.customer_id)
    where n.type not in ('A', 'B','C')
)
```

PS: Format your sql before posting, include logical model for beast answers and mention, what database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good, if you post your existing data and required result

```
select t1.id, t1.description, t1.name,
case when t1.name is null then 'NOT A CUSTOMER' end 
 from names t1
left outer join customer t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
where t2.type in ('A', 'B','C');
```